# Проблема с разрешением экрана

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть строка:

```
( Screen.SetResolution(res[res.Length-1].width, res[res.Length-1].height, true);)
```

которая делает разрешение экрана по умолчанию 1920x1080, но по неизвестной мне причине не делает этого, получается так что по умолчанию 640x480.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ResolutionSetting : MonoBehaviour {

    public Dropdown dropDown;
    Resolution[] res;

    void Start () {
        Resolution[] resolution = Screen.resolutions;
        res = resolution.Distinct().ToArray();
        string[] strRes = new string[res.Length];
        for (int i=0; i<res.Length; i++)
        {
            strRes[i] = res[i].ToString();
        }
        dropDown.ClearOptions();
        dropDown.AddOptions(strRes.ToList());

        //разрешение по умолчанию
        Screen.SetResolution(res[res.Length-1].width, res[res.Length-1].height, true);
    }

    public void setres()
    {
        Screen.SetResolution(res[dropDown.value].width, res[dropDown.value].height, true);
    }
}
```

Все, проблема решена (кому интересно вот код)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ResolutionSetting : MonoBehaviour {


public Dropdown dropDown;
Resolution[] res;
public Slider slider;
public Text currentRes; //для вывода



void Start () {
   Resolution[] resolution = Screen.resolutions;
    res = resolution.Distinct().ToArray();

    string[] strRes = new string[res.Length];
    for (int i=0; i<res.Length; i++)
    {
        strRes[i] = res[i].ToString();
    }
    dropDown.ClearOptions();
    dropDown.AddOptions(strRes.ToList());
    dropDown.value = res.Length - 1;

    //разрешение по умолчанию
    Screen.SetResolution(res[res.Length-1].width, res[res.Length-1].height, true);
    //slider
    slider.maxValue = res.Length - 1;
    slider.wholeNumbers = true;
    slider.value = res.Length - 1;
    currentRes.text = res[(int)slider.value].width.ToString() + "x" + res[(int)slider.value].height.ToString();

}


public void setres()
{
    Screen.SetResolution(res[dropDown.value].width, res[dropDown.value].height, true);
}
public void SetResSlider()
{
    Screen.SetResolution(res[(int)slider.value].width, res[(int)slider.value].height, true);
    currentRes.text = res[(int)slider.value].width.ToString() + "x" + res[(int)slider.value].height.ToString();
}
```

}

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй с начала отключить диалоговое решение.в 
`star`

```
PlayerSettings.displayResolutionDialog = ResolutionDialogSetting.Disabled;
```

а потом уже `Screen.SetResolutian.....`